# Essential bit content - prove that we can't use less bits than that

Tags: information-theory

Let $H_0$ be $\log_2(|A|)$, where $A$ is a set.

Let $C$ be a compressor $C\colon A \to \{1,0\}^l \cup \bot$.

This is a silly question, because intuitively it seems obvious.

How can I prove that $l$ can't be less than $H_0$?

I can prove that $l = H_0$ is sufficient, but how can I prove that it can't be less.

Comment: Unless you put some conditions on $C$, you can even choose $l = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function wouldn't be one-to-one otherwise.

The size of the set in the left is $|A|$, and its image would be of size at most $2^l<2^{H_0}=|A|$, therefore, the function wouldn't be injective and thus you wont be able to de-compress some of the data.

Therefore it will be a lossy-compression for any $l<H_0$.